# Swift Transferred Data between View Controllers stays empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, transfer

I am new to Swift. I am trying to pass data between two View Controllers. The value I pass through from the first view controller is nil when used by the second view controller. I do not understand why this is happening.

This is my `tableView` function call in the first view controller. It gets the selected table cell's user information.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let user = User()


    if(messages.count > 0) {
        let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]

        guard let chatPartnerID = message.chatPartnerID() else {
            return
        }


        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(chatPartnerID)
        ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                else {
                    return
            }

            user.id = chatPartnerID
            user.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
            self.setupChatLogControllerForUser(user)

            }, withCancelBlock: nil)
    }else {
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        self.setupChatLogControllerForUser(user)
    }


}
```

`User` in an `NSObject` which I declare like so:

```
class User: NSObject {

  var id: String?
  var name: String?
  var email: String?
  var profileImageUrl: String?
}
```

The `setupChatLogControllerForUser(user)` method in the first view controller takes in the user parameter that is given in the `tableView` method and passed onto the second view controller (`ChatLogController`) like this:

```
 func setupChatLogControllerForUser(user: User) {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController()
    chatLogController.selectedUserID = user.id!
    chatLogController.user = user
}
```

My second View Controller method receives the data with this:

```
var selectedUserID = String()
var user = User()
```

The second view controller also has a `handleSend` method which is linked to a button on my storyboard through `IBAction`.

```
func handleSend() {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")
    let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
    let toID = self.selectedUserID
    let fromID = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
    let timestamp: NSNumber = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

    let values = ["text": messageInputField.text!, "toID": toID, "fromID": fromID, "timestamp": timestamp]
    childRef.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        let userMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("userMessages").child(fromID)

        let messageID = childRef.key
        userMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageID: 1])

        let recipientUserMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("userMessages").child(toID)
        recipientUserMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageID: 1])

    }

}
```

This method is where the problem is occurring. I set `toID` equal to the `selectedUserID`. In the debugger, I can see the `selectedUserID` populated with a string when the view controller segues to the `ChatLogController`. Why is the value of `selectedUserID` variable nil when the method is called?

I understand that passing in the `selectedUserID` and the `User` object is redundant, I just wanted to see if the problem was something with the String variable being passed between the classes, but it stays nil.

Any help would be awesome!

**EDIT:** 
I am using a segue to switch between my view controllers

Comment: how to you move from your first vc to 2nd vc? segue or programatically?

Comment: you should perform segue instead of new a ChatLogController()

Comment: The issue is `ChatLogController()`. That's a new empty instance instead of the expected controller in the storyboard.

Comment: @ivy_p are you using segue or programmatically?

Comment: @GaneshKumar I am using a segue

Comment: If you're using a segue, pass your data in a `prepareForSegue` method.  As @vadian says, don't create a new controller object yourself, use the one that the segue creates for you.

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate **ChatLogController** for passing data because if you set up the **NavigationController** properly, then he is going to instantiate for you.

```
func setupChatLogControllerForUser(user: User) {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController()
    chatLogController.selectedUserID = user.id!
    chatLogController.user = user
}
```

So if you want to pass data to **ChatLogController**, you should use **prepareForSegue** method for this purpose.

---

I am going to provide a basic example how you can mimic this type of functionality:

This is the **result**:

[image]

---

This is my storyboard:

Note that the name of the **segue** is **showDetail** as you can see in image.

[image]

---

This is the code of my **TableViewController**:

When I touch a cell on the **TableViewController**, the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method is called, then I access the cell selected and set the value to **dataToSend** variable, finally I call **performSegueWithIdentifier** in order to navigate to the **ViewController**.

But right before it goes to **ViewController**, **prepareForSegue** method is called so you have the opportunity here to pass any variable that **ViewController** expects, in this case I am passing **dataToSend** to **ViewController's dataSent** variable.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var dataToSend = ""

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    dataToSend = cell!.textLabel!.text!

    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: nil)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
      if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController {
        viewController.dataSent = dataToSend
      }
    }
  }

}
```

---

This the code for **ViewController**:

for then I can show the value in a label.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

  var dataSent = String()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.text = dataSent
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation, it worked!